# org.apache.cxf.staxutils.DepthExceededStaxException caused by innerElementCountThreshold:50000

Tags: cxf

I am using apache cxf 2.6.10, and while processing a call I always get DepthExceededException. The documentation says I can override these values, but how can I do that? I tried defining those property in the bean it does not work. I tried setting them in cxf:bus it does not works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by increasing value of static field `innerElementCountThreshold`. I set it in my code like this:

```
StaxUtils.setInnerElementCountThreshold(200000);
```

Comment: I did not get it? I asked a question about the error, and while playing I got to the root of it and found out the faulty code or rather limiting code, which I duly pointed out the solution for?